# What is the difference in level curves from 2 to 3 dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Trouble with intuition on level curves.

In 3 D "level" can also be vertical, is that true?

I assume they can be level to ANY of the axis and my second **question** is
 what is a level curve  when using only 2D?

Comment: If the domain is $n$-dimensional then generically a level set is $(n-1)$-dimensional.

Comment: what's the level set of y = mx + b ?

Comment: It depends whether you mean $f(x,y)=y-mx-b$ or $f(x)=mx+b$; the notation doesn't make that so clear. For the former, it is a line with slope $m$; for the latter, it is just a point $x=(c-b)/m$.

Comment: Equations don't have level sets; _mappings_ have level sets. Could you please clarify your question, perhaps by editing in representative examples that confuse you?

Comment: Yes, that was sloppy on my part...should have been f(x) which is a mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but I *think* I know the general concept you're after, so here goes.

When I think of level curves, I like to think of the analogy of an island where you can vary the water level. A "3D" function that maps two coordinates to a single output $z = f(x,y)$ can be thought of as defining the surface of the earth around an island. The level curves of $f$ can be thought of as the various shorelines you get as you change the water level up and down.

We can play the same game in 2D where we have a single input, single output function $y = f(x)$ which can be thought of as defining the surface of a two dimensional world, and whose water levels are horizontal lines. In this case, the level "curves" are the particular set of intersection points that a given horizontal line makes with the graph of $y = f(x)$.

Observe that the level curves of a surface embedded in 3D space are curves in 2D space, and the level "curves" of a curve embedded in 2D space are points in 1D space. Thus, if you imagine a 4D function like $w = f(x,y,z)$ which defines a 3D solid embedded in 4D space (and hence not really visualizable), the level curves will be 2D surfaces embedded in 3D space (hence they are often referred to as *level surfaces*).

As for your first question, *can level sets be taken with respect to any axis?* I think the answer is *No*. When we talk about the level curves of a *function* from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. takes possibly multiple inputs, but returns only one output), we usually mean the set of intersection points the function makes with a constant function of the same dimension. That is, sets of the form
$$ \{(x_1, ..., x_n)\colon\ f(x_1, ..., x_n) = c\} $$
where $c$ represents the "water level".

This geometrically means the "water levels" are always taken to be perpendicular to the *output* axis (e.g. $y$ in 2D, $z$ in 3D, $w$ in 4D, etc.)

However, this is math. If you want to define level curves a different way whereby you *can* take level curves with respect to other axes (whatever that means), you're more than free to do so. The real question is if there is any reason to do so.

Comment: no there is no reason to do so ...i am  having trouble understanding how the level set xy =3 is the level set of xy =z and how minimizing  f( x,y ) = x^2 + y^2 given this level curve as the constraint must necessarily exist ...so maybe if I can visualize the graph the  Lagrange multipliers method would be more intuitive to me.  What does z = xy look like in order for a level set to be xy = 3?

Comment: it's this:  at the minimum , level curve of f is tangent to hyperbola g = 3 . I would like to visualize this because the Lagrange proof is trivial ...what is not trivial is picturing these animals overlap by necessity.